# Difference between "prior to" and "before"

Tags: grammar

I have read on the internet that prior to is a formal term for before and "prior to" is used when a past moment is relevant to the present one. However, I didn't understand the meaning of second explanation. Please explain with examples

Comment: There's no difference in meaning. Anything that happened before something else happened prior to that thing, and vice versa. _Prior to_ is just more formal language that is thought to befit the high opinion of its readers and especially its writer. In other words, it falutes higher.

Comment: Welcome, Akshit Raj. The way it's supposed to work is that you provide examples showing how far you got and where and how you stopped understanding.

When you didn't understand the "meaning of second explanation…" which second explanation was that, please?

"Prior to" is a more formal term for "before" and either can be used when a past moment is relevant to the present. How are there two explanations there?

Could counting that as two explanations explain the problem?

Comment: In reporting, a distinction is sometimes made between 'previous' and 'prior', namely, that the previous, say, month, is just that, but the prior month is the month previous to the previous month, which allows a 3-month comparison of activity: current month, current month minus 1, and current month minus 2.